# Setting up a Filetree with Files from a Database

Tags: php, jquery, sql-server, database

So I have to put up a Filetree based on a database, but I am totally lost in this.

I tried using this as a base Model: http://labs.abeautifulsite.net/archived/phpFileTree/demo/demo_jquery.php

And even used this as some sort of Tutorial:
http://www.kensodev.com/2009/05/22/using-jquery-tree-for-database-data/

But I just can't seem to get along with all this...

What I am trying to do is: I have some Data in a Database. All of this Data has some Phrases in it have different Phrases A to G. I now Need to sort it after Phrase A, then Sort it further after Phrase B and lastly all Data, that have the same Phrase C should be seen (Some Folder and subfolder like).

I also tried it with div and table but well let's say it didn't work :D

Now please can someone just tell me where in heavens i have to put my DB Server Name, PW and so on and my DB "Select" in all of the above to get this thing working.

Comment: Also, that tutorial is for C# and you are doing it in PHP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly you want to have a page that when a user clicks on a link it gets some data from the database and displays it with an alert using AJAX/jQuery

Add a PHP file in your root directory with

```
<?php
//edit for your server/database
$username = "username";
$password = "password";
$hostname = "hostname";
$dbname = "database-name";

//to connect to the database
$db = new PDO('mysql:host='.$hostname.';dbname='.$dbname.';charset=utf8', $username, $password);
?>
```

It's pretty straightforward really, if you need to sort the data many times then you are probably doing something wrong or you could try with a JOIN clause.

Assuming you want to display the link the user clicked (and fetch the link from the database), you might as well add a php_file_tree function in another php file like this

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET['Phrase'])){
    $needle = $_GET['Phrase'];
}else{$needle = null;}
function php_file_tree($directory, $javascript){
//include previous file with connection details
global $needle, $db;

//I'm not sure what you are looking for in the database
$value = "value"

//could be ASC or DESC $needle or $value
$query = "SELECT table.Phrases FROM table WHERE Phrases = '{$needle}' ORDER BY A DESC;";
$sth = $db->prepare($query);
$sth->execute();

$data = $sth->fetchAll();

return $javascript = preg_replace('/\[\[.*?\]\]/', 'link', $javascript);

}
//should give you the alert
echo php_file_tree($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'], "javascript:alert('You clicked on [link]');");
?>
```

Also add this to your HTML page

```
<script src="jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="php_file_tree_jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    var fetchUrl = 'path-to-the-php-file-with-the-function'
    var fetchNeedle = $( "#link" ).html();
    $.get(fetchUrl.concat(fetchNeedle)).done(function(data) { Alert(data); });      

});
</script>
```

Reference: http://deocasion.org/blog/ajax-dropdown/

Comment: Thanks for the fast answer but I already got so far, my question was, where i should put this into that jquery plugin for it to work, maybe I'm just too stupid to see it though.

Comment: It's okay, you just need to explain yourself a little better, check edited answer.

Comment: Thanks so much, this really helped an awful lot already. I think I am able to get along with the rest along, but if you have time (and wanna help, but really you helped more than enough, this is just for, well if you're bored or smth...), I already have an integrated search function in my html, with which People can search for the first few Digits in Phrase A (Which is a number) and only stuff containing this is showing up then. So it's not from a link. I fear, that if I Change too much from your Code it won't work properly, thats why I ask before. But seriously you helped enough already :D

Comment: I'm glad I could help, looks easy enough but you should ask a new question tho. Good luck ;)